# Angular BehaviorSubject subscription fires only once

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular service with a boolean property called **must_checkout**. My service also contains a property called **observable_must_checkout** which is a BehaviorSubject looking into **must_checkout**.

Then, In my component I subcribe to **observable_must_checkout**.

This works and the component receives the event the first time **must_checkout** changes. However this only fires once, and subsequent changes to **must_checkout** are not working:

Service:

```
import { Injectable,  Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

export class OrderingService
{

  must_checkout: boolean;
  observable_must_checkout = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.must_checkout);

  constructor([...])
  {
    this.observable_must_checkout = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.must_checkout);
  }

  ChangeSomething()
  {
    console.log("changing the value here...");
    this.must_checkout = true;
  }


}
```

Parent component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OrderingService } from 'src/app/services/ordering.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-settle',
  templateUrl: './settle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./settle.component.css']
})

export class SettleComponent implements OnInit
{
  constructor(private OrderingService: OrderingService) { }

  ngOnInit()
  {
        this.basket = new OrderingService();
        this.basket.observable_must_checkout.subscribe((newValue: boolean) => { alert("value changed: " + newValue)  });

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.basket.observable_must_checkout.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not seeing a call to next(), which is how you fire new events to the current subscribers of your BehaviorSubject. You are looking for something like this.

```
  ChangeSomething()
  {
    console.log("changing the value here...");
    this.observable_must_checkout.next(true); 
  }
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/

Also, you don't need to intialize the subject in the constructor since you do it a few lines above:

```
  observable_must_checkout = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(this.must_checkout);

  constructor([...])
  {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. When you create your BehaviorSubject, it uses the value `must_checkout` as its initial value and then discards it. This means any changes to `must_checkout` will have *zero* impact on your observable. This is equivelant to what you're doing. Copy and past this code here to see how the change in `mustCheckOut` does not emit a new signal.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4jynuj?devtoolsheight=60

```
import { of, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


let mustCheckOut:boolean = false;
let obsMustCheckOut: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(mustCheckOut);


obsMustCheckOut.asObservable().subscribe(signal => {
  console.log("I got a signal!", signal)
})

// This does not work. 
// Even though you change the source `mustCheckout`, the BehaviorSubject does not listen to the change in this variable. You must ping a subject which can emit a signal to any subscribers. 
setTimeout(() => {
  mustCheckOut = true
}, 100)
```

It sounds like you want to emit a new signal each time `must_checkout` changes. You need to convert your `must_checkout` variable to something that can emit signals! Then anything subscribed to it will be impacted.

```
import { of, BehaviorSubject,Subject, Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';


let mustCheckOut: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
let obsMustCheckOut: Observable<boolean> = mustCheckOut.asObservable().pipe(
  tap((signal) => console.log('I got the signal', signal)),
  // other manipulation or async requests can occur here.
)


obsMustCheckOut.subscribe(signal => {
  console.log("Here is the current signal!!!", signal)
})


setTimeout(() => {
  mustCheckOut.next(true)
}, 100)

setTimeout(() => {
  mustCheckOut.next(false)
}, 2600)


setTimeout(() => {
  mustCheckOut.next(true)
}, 5500)
```

I hope this helps you. Let me know if you need more clarification. Further reading can be found here: https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html

Answer (score 0):

> I had the same problem, but different cause.

This was my declaration.

```
  private clients: BehaviorSubject<ClientSummary[]> = new BehaviorSubject(undefined);
  public clients$: Observable<ClientSummary[]> = this.clients.asObservable();
```

And how it was being consumed

```
 this.clientService.clients$.subscribe(clients => {
    // do something with clients  
    console.log(clients);
 });
```

When the page loaded, the observable fired with the following log

```
undefined
```

However, when next was called on the `BehaviorSubject`, the observable did not fire again.

```
  this.clients.next([/* some clients*/]);
```

**Can you see the problem?**

It's very subtle and took me a while to track down.

**Solution**

Update the initial value!

```
 private clients: BehaviorSubject<ClientSummary[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

I don't know why, but with this change the observable not updates each time next is called on the `BehaviorSubject`.

As for why I had undefined in there in the first place? 
Probably copy and paste!